# RobotFramework: Goes

Tags: xpath, robotframework

Below is code where i go to a new window. I do a screenshot to ensure that i am on the right window

```
${url}=    Get Element Attribute   xpath=//*[contains(text(),'Download certificate')]@href 

Select Window Containing Url  ${url}
Page Screenshot  certificates
Wait Until Element Is visible  xpath=//*[contains(text(),"SUCCESSFULLY COMPLETED THE MODULE")]
```

Not found according to error message.

```
Element locator 'xpath=//*[contains(text(),"SUCCESSFULLY COMPLETED THE MODULE")]' did not match any elements after 30 seconds
```

However i know from firebug that this xpath will match on the page. My uneducated theory is that the focus is still on the former page - would this be correct and regardless, what can i do to ensure that commands go to the correct new page?

Comment: you are taking a screenshot. When you look at the screenshot, do you see the element you are looking for? Have you tried using the [log source](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Log%20Source) keyword so that you can see if what you're looking for is actually in the source of the page? Maybe the text is actually mixed case but css is being used to make it appear in uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Select Window    new`.
See documentation [here](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Select%20Window)